# An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code. Cannot figure out issue

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I have tried using methods that others have used here to fix their issue but none of them are working for me. I am new to the ASP.NET framework and cannot understand why the information I am trying to send to my database isn't working. Also, Visual Studios isn't giving em an error until I try to submit the new data which makes it difficult for me to pinpoint the problem.

```
namespace ylena_exercise
{
    public partial class KnockoutBind : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ylena_exercise;Integrated Security=True");
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            GridView1.Visible = false;
        }

        protected void AddBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Customers ('"+numid.Text+"','"+txtcustomer.Text+"','"+txtcontact.Text+"','"+txtaddress.Text+"','"+txtcity.Text+"','"+numpostcode.Text+"','"+txtcountry.Text+"')",con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            GridView1.DataBind();
            Label1.Visible = true;
            Label1.Text = "Data Stored Successfully!";
            numid.Text = "";
            txtcustomer.Text = "";
            txtcontact.Text = "";
            txtaddress.Text = "";
            txtcity.Text = "";
            numpostcode.Text = "";
            txtcountry.Text = "";                
        }
    }
}
```

[image: dbo.Customers data file]

[image: Message after clicking "Submit" button]

Is there something wrong with my data? Or perhaps the issue is ExecuteNonQuery?

Comment: Try the sql this way: `insert into Customers (column1_name, column2_name) values ('column1_value', column2_value)`

Comment: Usually `SqlException` text contains error text provided by SQL server. Read it more precisely and probably you'll realize the reason. Or post it in your question for someone to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey so I managed to figure out why ExecuteNonQuery was giving me issues. It turns out I simply did not match the table columns names with the variables in the SQL command.

Sorry for all of the trouble guys! Nevertheless, I appreciate all of the helpful suggestions and advice.

Answer (score 2):

You missed `Values` in your `insert` statement your code should be like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Customers values('"+numid.Text+"',....
```

Also you should always use  [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Customers values(@numid,...");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numid",numid.Text);
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will try it that way.

Comment: @gabed123...You're Welcome. Although specify the type directly and use the Value property is more better than AddWithValue. Check this:http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: @Soner unfortunately, even after making the adjustments, it is still breaking and giving me the message "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code" and the ExecuteNonQuery Connection property has not been initialized

Comment: @gabed123...Are you sure the number of columns in your database is 7?

Comment: Yes @user2946329, I believe there are 7 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Include column names in your sql and set the values like this:

```
var command = "insert into customers (id, name, contact, address, city, postcode, country) values (@id, @name, @contact, @address, @city, @postcode, @country)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", numid.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtcustomer.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact", txtcontact.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtaddress.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", txtcity.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postcode", numpostcode.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", txtcountry.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

[Courtesy: Soner Gönül & user2946329]

Comment: `string.Format` does **not** prevent SQL Injection vulnerability. Prepared statements should be provided.

Comment: I have tried it this way and I am still getting an error at cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  with the message "InvalidOperationException was unhanded by user code. Sorry if I seem helpless.